# Python Importing other Functions in Package

Tags: python, command-line, import

I have something like the following structure in my python package:

```
package/
--functions/
  --functionsA.py
  --functionsB.py
--utility/
  --utils_printing.py
  --utils_server.py
```

My goal is to be able to import `package` within any of the contained `.py` files in a way which works when I execute a specific function in one of the `.py` files from the command line.

Right now, if I want to use a server function in `functionsA.py` then I just throw a 
`from package.utility.utils_server import server_function` 
at the top of `functionsA.py`. Debugging with PyCharm, this works.

Now I'm trying to use pyheat to show me where my code needs to be optimized, but it requires that I run a given file as a script from the command line, but if I try to run `pyheat functionsA.py` then I'll get an error like `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package'`.

Comment: Set the environment variable PYTHONPATH=<path to your package>

Comment: Never heard of pyheat until now. [line_profiler](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler) is probably better for optimising code because it gives you the actual times.